TypeScript zod type safe function with generic parameters
I am using zod to validate forms in a TypeScript project.
I have a function that can take, for a given form schema, the form values and another function requestFunc that takes the form values as input.
I would like to make this function type safe in order to make sure I am not mixing up different forms.
So I tried using TypeScript's Generics declaration like so:
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodSchema>(
  formData: z.infer<T>,
  requestFunc: (formData: z.infer<T>) => void
): void {}

But it doesn't work as expected, I never get any type error unless I define two forms with differently named attributes AND I use the function like so:
schemaTest<typeof schemaA>(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData: z.infer<typeof schemaC>) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);

Here is a complete example that tests the different scenarios, I added comments showing the types or errors:
import { z } from 'zod';

// The test function
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodSchema>(
  formData: z.infer<T>,
  requestFunc: (formData: z.infer<T>) => void
): void {}

// Example schemas
const schemaA = z.object({
  email: z.string().email('Invalid email address'),
  password: z.string().min(6, 'Password must be at least 6 characters long')
});

const schemaB = z.object({
  email: z.string().email('Invalid email address') // Changed property name
});

const schemaC = z.object({
  othername: z.string().email('Invalid email address') // Changed property name
});

// Example 1
// function schemaTest<z.ZodType<any, z.ZodTypeDef, any>>(formData: any, requestFunc: (formData: any) => void): void
schemaTest(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData: z.infer<typeof schemaB>) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);


// Example 2
// function schemaTest<z.ZodObject<{
//     email: z.ZodString;
//     password: z.ZodString;
// }, "strip", z.ZodTypeAny, {
//     email: string;
//     password: string;
// }, {
//     email: string;
//     password: string;
// }>>(formData: {
//     email: string;
//     password: string;
// }, requestFunc: (formData: {
//     email: string;
//     password: string;
// }) => void): void
schemaTest<typeof schemaA>(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData: z.infer<typeof schemaB>) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);


//Example 3
// Argument of type '(formData: z.infer<typeof schemaC>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(formData: { email: string; password: string; }) => void'.
//  Types of parameters 'formData' and 'formData' are incompatible.
//  Property 'othername' is missing in type '{ email: string; password: string; }' but required in type '{ othername: string; }'.ts(2345)
schemaTest<typeof schemaA>(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData: z.infer<typeof schemaC>) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);

// Example 4
// function schemaTest<z.ZodType<any, z.ZodTypeDef, any>>(formData: any, requestFunc: (formData: any) => void): void
schemaTest(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData: z.infer<typeof schemaC>) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);



Problem
The issue here is that TypeScript cannot infer type T correctly based on the parameters passed into a function.
original function implementation:
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodSchema>(
  formData: z.infer<T>,
  requestFunc: (formData: z.infer<T>) => void
): void {}

The z.infer<T> utility type extracts the inferred type from a Zod schema T. However, once inferred, the resulting type no longer carries any information about T itself. It becomes a concrete type (e.g., { email: string; password: string; }), losing the association with the original schema T. TypeScript cannot reverse-engineer the generic type T from the inferred types.
Solution
You need to let TypeScript know how T would look like. It can be done in two ways:
Option 1
Add schema itself as function parameter so that TypeScript can infer T out of it.
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
  schema: T,
  formData: z.infer<T>,
  requestFunc: (formData: z.infer<T>) => void
): void {}

//Example
schemaTest(
  schemaA,
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  }),
  (formData) => {
    console.log(formData);
  }
);

Option 2
Instead of passing the schema as a parameter, you can modify your function to accept a higher-order function that carries the generic type information.
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(
  requestFunc: (formData: z.infer<T>) => void
): (formData: z.infer<T>) => void {
  return (formData: z.infer<T>) => {
    requestFunc(formData);
  };
}

//Example
const handleSchemaA = schemaTest<typeof schemaA>((formData) => {
  console.log(formData);
});

handleSchemaA(
  schemaA.parse({
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: '123456'
  })

);

UPD: Based on comment
To make it work, perhaps, you could add additional generic parameter that will check that formData and requestFunc are aligned on the same type:
U as z.infer<T>: By adding U as an explicit second generic parameter (U extends z.infer), you are tying formData and requestFunc’s parameter types strictly to the inferred type of schema.
The previous option uses z.infer<T> independently for formData and requestFunc, which may tell typescript to make loosened check on function. With the new approach, you make sure both parameters are of the exactly same type.
// The test function
function schemaTest<T extends z.ZodTypeAny, U extends z.infer<T>>(
  schema: T,
  formData: U,
  requestFunc: (formData: U) => void
): void {}


With Option 1 the example number 2 is still accepted by typescript.
I am trying to avoid Option2, I just want to pass a form and the function I want to use.

@QuantumMartin please let me know if the latter works as expected. Interesting question, actually. Keen on solving it as I'm actively learning this mess with type inference :)

Thanks
I think it didn't fix it entirely, if you want to try it yourself you can copy paste the example I wrote in a ts file.
